# ADF Faces and jQuery integration

Tags: jquery, jsf, oracle-adf

Is ADF Faces and jQuery incompatible? In some of my pages I have used jQuery to perfect my design. Since ADF Faces doesn't have component like `<p/>` or `<h1/>` and if I use these tags then ADF behaves unexpectedly. So by jQuery I can wrap some components by the tags not available in ADF. Are their any chances of error or misbehavior of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OTN Discussion Forum, jQuery could break the ADF page lifecycle.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2366442

People have managed to make them work together:

- http://george.maggessy.com/2010/08/adf-and-jquery-working-together.html
- http://codingwithpassion.blogspot.ca/2011/01/using-jquery-in-oracle-adf-faces.html

Unless you have no other choice, I would use JSF 2.0 and the latest version of ADF. There have been substantial improvements over its UI controls, look & feel, and more.

Comment: Thanks. It's me the OP of the thread of the OTN Discussion Forum me. :)